# How to fix logstash lock error with input-jdbc-plugin?

Tags: logstash

I'm using logstash with input-jdbc-plugin and output-elasticsearch-plugin, when I try to sync massive data from PostgreSQL to elasticsearch, I got these error message as below:

```
[WARN ][logstash.shutdownwatcher ] {"inflight_count"=>0, "stalling_thread_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>22, "name"=>"[main]<jdbc", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.9/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:170:in `join'"}, {"thread_id"=>20, "name"=>"[main]>worker0", "current_call"=>"[...]/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:138:in `lock'"}]}}
```

I expect know why they can not run with massive data and how to fix it. thanks a lot

Comment: This is warning message not error, can you provide full ERROR and WARN logs?